# Sending mail from Oracle APEX PL/SQL code using an Apache proxy

Tags: oracle, apache, email

I'm having problems sending mails from APEX, I'm using XAMPP, APEX is running on an Apache Tomcat server, and I'm Mercury SMTP to send the mails. The problem is when I execute the PL/SQL code it doesn't encounter any errors, but the emails don't show up in the APEX admin mail queue, nor do they arrive at the destination email address.

Here are the PL/SQL codes I tried using.
APEX_MAIL:

```
    create or replace procedure PROC_SEND_MAIL(p_from varchar2, p_to varchar2, p_subject varchar2, p_body varchar2)
    as   
        l_id number; 
    begin 
      l_id := APEX_MAIL.SEND(    
      p_to, p_from, p_subject, p_body); 

      APEX_MAIL.push_queue;
      commit;
end PROC_SEND_MAIL;
```

UTL_SMTP:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SEND_SMTP (msg_to varchar2, msg_subject varchar2, msg_text varchar2 )
IS
   c utl_smtp.connection;
   rc integer; 
   msg_from varchar2(50) := 'Sender'; 
   mailhost VARCHAR2(30) := 'My apache proxy IP address';

BEGIN
   c := utl_smtp.open_connection(mailhost, 25); -- SMTP on port 25 
   utl_smtp.helo(c, mailhost);
   utl_smtp.mail(c, msg_from);
   utl_smtp.rcpt(c, msg_to);

   utl_smtp.data(c,'From: Sender' || utl_tcp.crlf || 'To: ' || msg_to || utl_tcp.crlf || 'Subject: ' || msg_subject || utl_tcp.crlf || msg_text);
   utl_smtp.quit(c);

EXCEPTION
   WHEN UTL_SMTP.INVALID_OPERATION THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(' Invalid Operation in Mail attempt 
      using UTL_SMTP.');
      WHEN UTL_SMTP.TRANSIENT_ERROR THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(' Temporary e-mail issue - try again'); 
      WHEN UTL_SMTP.PERMANENT_ERROR THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(' Permanent Error Encountered.'); 
end send_smtp;
```

Of course when I stop the Mercury SMTP I'm getting an error stating the service is not found, so I guess I configured the SMTP properly.

If it's a problem with the proxy, how do I configure the Apache httpd.conf file to know which emails should it serve?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Tamas

Comment: First thing I'd do is put a `RAISE;` in all those exception handlers.

Comment: Check `apex_mail_log` to see if the emails got sent (at least as far as Apex is concerned).

Comment: They don't show in the mail queue, I guess that means they got sent?

Comment: By the way, I'm trying to use Google's smtp server(smtp.google.com) right now, I got everything configured, but I'm getting the ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available error. (when I'm using the google smtp the mails do show up in the queue with the above mentioned error)

Comment: Okay, a little bit of clarification here: I configured in apex admin to use smtp.google.com as the default smtp server. When I'm trying to send a mail using UTL_SMTP, the mail won't show up in the mail queue, but when I'm using UTL_MAIL or APEX_MAIL they show up in the mail queue, but with the above mentioned service not available error.

Comment: UTL_SMTP and UTL_MAIL don't use any queue, they attempt to connect directly to the target in that session. Only APEX_MAIL has a queue.

Comment: ORA-29278 means that your code is successfully connecting to a server on that port, but that server is returning error 421 Service not available. I'm not sure if google smtp servers respond to port 25 any more, they may require SSL/TLS encrypted sessions e.g. on port 587.

Comment: You were right Jeffrey, I didn't configure the mercury smtp properly, although I still only got it working with apex_mail, but not utl_mail or utl_smtp, but since it gets the job done, I'll settle for it.
So basically it looks like this now: apex is configured so it sends the mails to localhost, where the mercury smtp listens on port 25, then mercury forwards it to the gmail smtp, and finally the gmail smtp forwards it to the endpoint.
By the way, do you think it's possible to do the whole process without the gmail smtp? I'd like to bypass gmails 99 message limitation if possible.

Comment: If you can get apex_mail to work, you should be able to get utl_smtp to work if you get it to do the same thing. Are you using basic authentication? My suggestion would be to try another smtp gateway - I've used my ISP before, but now I use Mailgun.

Comment: Yeah, I might look into the utl_smtp configuration later, but the way I see it it really is only preference which one I use. 
So this mailgun stuff looks good, but as I see to properly get it working I need to make an own domain, and set up the proper dns records, right?
Might I ask if you are using your own domain or the provided sandbox one? (in sandbox I can't send mails to every domain, eg. gmail, so it's quite a problem)

Comment: I use my own domain. It's not difficult, and the mailgun instructions walk you through setting up the dns.

Comment: Yes, I see now, I'll put these tips to good use, thanks for the help Jeffrey!